# How to external access a ray remote multiple node cluster?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, remote-access, ray

I have a question concerning the access of a ray multi node cluster:

> Considering a deployed cluster on AWS or kubernetes, how can a
>   seperate python process from outside the cluster run tasks on the
>   cluster?

e.g. A Web client tries to invoke python tasks,that should run within the Remote cluster.

EDIT: It comes down to the question:

> Is there a Ray native API to connect to a remote cluster from a computer/server outside of the actual cluster?

Answer (score 0):

https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy-on-kubernetes.html#running-ray-programs says you can get a shell on the ray pods and run the tasks or create a new Kubernetes job.

So the question boils down to how do I connect to the Kubernetes cluster from a web application.

You can connect to the Kubernetes cluster from a web application using one of the clients in https://github.com/kubernetes-client. Here is the Python one https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

Comment: I was rather thinking about a ray API to connect to a cluster, like it is stated here: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoscaling.html ....You can use ray exec to conveniently run commands on clusters. Note that scripts you run should connect to Ray via ray.init(address="auto").....

Comment: I mean, there needs to be a ray native API to connect to a remote cluster?

Comment: Ray is also seeming to go Kubernetes native by creating a k8s operator https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/6328

Comment: Doesn't seem to have a ray native api all I could find are https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/ray-0.6.0/api.html#ray-start and https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoscaling.html#attaching-to-a-running-cluster

Comment: I was just thinking in context of Kubernetes cluster, not the ray cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to remote Ray servers (e.g. running in a different container or on a different machine within the same cluster [1]) on the client-server port (10001 by default) rather than the Ray Core (GCS) server (6379 by default), using the standard `ray.init()`, as long as you prefix the URL or IP with `ray://`:

For example:

```py
import ray

ray_cluster_ip_or_url = "<remote url redacted>"

# ray_api_server_port = 6379 # Ray API (GCS) server port
ray_client_server_port = 10001 # Ray client-server port

# caution: it is necessary to prefix the URL or IP with "ray://" 
# to be able to connect to the client-server port
ray.init(address=f"ray://{ray_cluster_ip_or_url}:{ray_client_server_port}",
         ignore_reinit_error=True)
```

*More info*

This alternative method does not require the `ray://` prefix, but is deprecated:

```py
[..]

ray.util.connect(conn_str=f"{ray_cluster_ip_or_url}:{ray_client_server_port}", secure=False)
```

[1] The restriction of client-server connections to the same k8s cluster is due to the binary protocols being used by Ray, which cannot be passed though an HTTP proxy outside of the cluster. This is why you need to connect to service ports, not standard HTTP(S) ports.